# How to integrate Node JS in Django?

Tags: node.js, django, socket.io

I'm trying to find how to implement Node JS in Django, I have seen some posts about how powerfull can they be together Django in management and Node Js in events (like this post https://www.cuelogic.com/blog/how-to-use-both-django-nodejs-as-backend-for-your-application) but I don't know how to integrate Node JS in Django and make it work it, it said that **"*All you need is a way to connect the socket.io server running on Node.JS with Django app.*"** but I have no idea how to do that, so if you guys have an idea or have had work with it before I'll appreciate if you can help to this newbie trying to be a dev.

Comment: What use case do you have for using node/javascript that you can't do in Python? If you are just getting started, stick to one of either Python or Node.js.

Comment: ...and that article is pretty bad, they've just thrown some words together.

Comment: ok, I'll follow your suggestion and I'll try to find how to add events in Python (basically that's the only reason why I was trying to combine them), thanks.

Comment: Is this just to push data to a web client like [socket.io](https://socket.io/)? Python has a [socket.io implementation](https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/).